# Why the regex to mark beginning of line doesn't work?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Why the commented regex doesn't behave the same as uncommented regex? I thought '^' also marks beginning of line. isn't it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
     std::string str ("this subject has a submarine as a subsequence");
     std::regex re ("\\b(sub)([^ ]*)");
     // std::regex re ("^(sub)([^ ]*)");
     // std::regex re ("(^sub)([^ ]*)");
     
      std::cout << "entire matches:"; 
      std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;
      std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> a ( str.begin(), str.end(), re );
      while (a!=rend) std::cout << " [" << *a++ << "]";
      std::cout << std::endl;
  
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `[^ ]` it means everything except space (more general when use `^` in brackets it means not)

Comment: @Alireza - what does \\b stand for?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘doesn’t work’? What is the expected output of that code (and why?), and what is the observed output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working just fine.  It can't match anything because your line doesn't start with the letter "sub," it starts with the letters "The"

To explain these regexes:

- `\\b(sub)([^ ]*)`

Start of new **word**, begins with sub, followed by some number of non-space characters.  Two capture groups, one for "sub" and one for the other characters.

- `^(sub)([^ ]*)`

Start of new **line**, begins with sub, followed by some number of non-space characters.  Two capture groups, one for "sub" and one for the other characters.

- `(^sub)([^ ]*)`

[**EDIT**: Fixed, thanks John] Same as above, but with the anchor being part of the capture group.

Comment: `^` in bracket doesn't mean the start of line

Comment: @Alireza: Correct, but the ^ outside of a bracket, as seen in the second regex, does.

Comment: I think he means the first regex.

Comment: @Alireza: He asked about the commented-out regex

Comment: @DanielMcLaury  - your 3rd point is probably not correct i.e about (^sub)([^ ]*)

Answer (score 1):

These two tries to match a line starting with `sub` followed by 0 or more non-spaces, like
`sub` in the string `sub bub`:

```
std::regex re ("^(sub)([^ ]*)");
std::regex re ("(^sub)([^ ]*)");
```

The `^` anchor in that context is what makes it only match the beginning of a line.

Comment: Are you sure that the regex std::regex re ("(^sub)([^ ]*)"); too matches line beginning with sub? From other answer it looks like matching not beginning with s and followed by ub.

Comment: @John I didn't look at the other answer closely but yes I'm sure. The other answer is probably wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`^` in brackets means not and in all other places means the start of line (except when you escape the ^)

your uncommented pattern: `\b(sub)([^ ]*)`

explanation:

- `\b` it stands for the boundary that means the space between one char from `\w` and one char from `\W`

**Note:** `\w` means all digits between 0-9 and all characters between a-z and A-Z and underline character, also `\W` means everything except \w so space belongs to \W

- `(sub)` it match "sub" string
- `([^ ]*)` it means everything except space (more general when use ^ in brackets it means not so it means everything except space because in front of ^ you used one space)

Comment: Can we safely say that \b will capture individual words?

Comment: words? no we can't say that.